# How to convert ES5/Angular/AMD pattern to ES6/Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, ecmascript-6

I am using the following pattern for of angular module definition:

```js
define(function(require) {
  var moduleId = require('module').id;
  var angular = require('angular');
  var ngModule = angular.module(moduleId, 
      [require('angular-xx1'), require('angular-xx2')]);

  ngModule.directive('myDirective', {/*...*/ });

  return moduleId;
});
```

This way, by exporting module name I can easily manage loading of the scripts during development and building for production is automatically handled by `require.js`. Furthermore I don't have to worry about module naming as `moduleId` is guaranteed to be unique.

Yesterday I have stumbled upon BabelJS (https://babeljs.io/) and its AMD loader plugin. It works very nicely but I have trouble using only ES6 syntax to manage my loading. The best I can come up with is having a mixed AMD/ES6, depending on the transpiler wrapping my code in the right AMD definition.

```
import angular from 'angular';
import {id} from 'module';
export default id;

let ngModule = angular.module(id,
    [require('angular-xx1'), require('angular-xx2')]);

ngModule.directive('myDirective');
```

I would love not to depend on any assumptions of a module loader here so I would love to get rid of having to write `require` and some way to get unique module id with importing `id`.

Comment: Why do you not know what your files are called? Both AMD and ES6 module loading are based on file name

Comment: I know roughly how dependencies are called, hence `require('angular-xx1')`. The dependency is most probably called `angular-xx1.js` but I don't want to know its angular module name, this is the whole point of exporting it automatically from `require('module').id`.

Comment: You don't have to know its module name for angular, you just have to know its file name (that's what it's required by) - do you know that?

Comment: Angular (at least 1.x) injects modules via their names, it does not handle or assume any script loading mechanism. Maybe you are mistaking it for Angular2 which is made specifically for ES6? Sorry if I misunderstood your point. I am using Angular 1.4.

Comment: I'm saying - while Angular 1.x injects scripts by module name ES6 loads them by file name, so you don't have to actually know the module name in advance just the file name.

Comment: Right but look at my ES5 file, it does import the script AND the module name automatically. To do the same with ES6 (to the extent of my knowledge) I would probably have to do:

    `import angularXx1Name from 'angular-xx1'; import angularXx2Name from 'angular-xx2'; angular.module('myFileName', [angularXx1Name, angularXx2Name]);`

which is very cumbersome